# How do I change the value of a .env var from command line in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, environment-variables

I'm on windows developing a white label app for android using React Native, and I would like to know if there is a way to change the value of a environment variable from command line on build. e.g: `some-kind-of-parameter react-native run-android` and on release `gradlew myappRelease`.

Comment: So you're asking how to change an environment variable in Windows, not in react native (which would run on Android which doesn't use environment variables by and large)?

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion, I just added more info about my problem.

Comment: In cmd hit: `set x=y`